# How do I convert a kernel .config file from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Tags: kernel, compiling, linux-kernel, configuration

At [this page](http://www.manticore-projects.com/content/en/software/guides/aspire522.htm) you can download a configuration file that lets you target a particular notebook architecture during the compilation of a new 32-bit Linux kernel.

I need a 64 bit version.

What do I have to do? I compiled a kernel 2-3 times in my life but I never touched a config file, I always have used an interactive menu.

Comment: just put the config file in the source directory as `.config`, I believe `make menuconfig` reads it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recommended answer, as the comment suggests, is to save it as `.config` in the top-level source directory, and then run `make xconfig` (GUI, easier) or `make menuconfig` (TUI) **on a 64-bit system**.

That said, to simply switch from 32-bit to 64-bit without changing anything else, a little editing at the beginning is all that's needed. Compare:

- Original (32-bit)

```
# CONFIG_64BIT is not set
CONFIG_X86_32=y
# CONFIG_X86_64 is not set
CONFIG_OUTPUT_FORMAT="elf32-i386"
CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="arch/x86/configs/i386_defconfig"
```

- "Converted" 64-bit

```
CONFIG_64BIT=y
# CONFIG_X86_32 is not set
CONFIG_X86_64=y
CONFIG_OUTPUT_FORMAT="elf64-x86-64"
CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig"
```

- Note that `CONFIG_X86=y` is *not touched*.

Comment: it's ok to compile a kernel on a different machine? I would like to use another machine that is faster than this.